# jQuery AJAX show detail on click wrong redirecting

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this script which is supposed to show details of `MeetingCenter` (by rendering partial view) on link click when I am on `/Home/EmployeeDetails/EmployeeId`. However it seems to redirect to `/Home/EmployeeDetails/home/meetingcenterdetail/` instead.

Piece of View

```
<a class="LoadMCDetail" href="javascript:void(0)" data-assigned-id="@Model.MeetingCentre.MeetingCenterId">@Model.MeetingCenter.Name</a>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".LoadMCDetail").click(function () {
                $("#MCDetail").load("home/meetingcenterdetail/", {
                    id: $(this).data('assigned-id')
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Piece of `Home` Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EmployeeDetails(string id)
{
    return View(await _employeeRepository.GetItemAsync(id));
}

public async Task<IActionResult> MeetingCenterDetail(string id)
{
    return PartialView("_MeetingCenterDetailPartial", await _meetingCenterReposiotry.GetItemAsync(id));
}
```

Comment: Do you have additional hyperlinks with the same class of 'LoadMCDetail' floating around?

Comment: As @Chad H mentioned I forgot slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#MCDetail").load("home/meetingcenterdetail/", {
                id: $(this).data('assigned-id')
            });
```

Try:

```
$("#MCDetail").load("/home/meetingcenterdetail/", {
                    id: $(this).data('assigned-id')
                });
```

Basically I added a slash in front of home, which is root relative.